# What DAW's support flexible pitch editing?

Tags: daw, pitch-shifting

I've been introduced to Logic Pro X recently, and one of my favorite features is the Flex Pitch functionality.  Unfortunately, I don't have a mac at home, so I'm looking for an alternative DAW with similar capabilities.  Are there any other DAWs with something like Flex Pitch?

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out Nuendo, Cubase and Pootools. They all have variable time/pitch stretching capabilities.

Comment: And don' t forget to mention Ableton Live which - I think - introduced the whole Timestretching-Marker-Thing...

Comment: Never used it, so I cannot comment on Ableton.